# How to remove waitedMS and ok from mongo db aggregation result?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am performing aggregation command in mongodb php application like below lines of code.

```
<?php

 $query =  array('$or' => array(
    array('employeeList'=>array('$exists' => false)),
    array('employeeList'=>array('$eq' => null)),
    array('employeeList'=>array('$eq' => ",")),
    array('employeeList'=>array('$eq' => ""))
));

$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$match' => $query
    ),
    array(
        '$lookup' => array(
            'from' => 'userTbl',
            'localField' => 'user_id',
            'foreignField' => 'uid',
            'as' => 'userdetails'
        )
    ),
);

$output = $this->db->broadcastTbl->aggregate($pipeline);
$result =array();
array_push($result, $output);
```

Now the output is displayed as

```
[{"waitedMS":0,"result":[{"_id":{"$id":"58d7a6561d78597411000029"},"broadcast_id":35,"studentList":"","employeeList":"999","mailTitle":"hello","broadcastMessage":"how","emailSent":"0","userdetails":[]},{"_id":....
...
"ok":1}]
```

I want to remove "waitedMS":0. "result":, and "ok":1 from  the json. The output should be like

```
[{"_id":{"$id":"58d7a6561d78597411000029"},"broadcast_id":35,"studentList":"","employeeList":"999","mailTitle":"hello","broadcastMessage":"how","emailSent":"0","userdetails":[]}, ...
]
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: I don't see any output here, but wouldn't that just be `$output["result"]` then?

Comment: you are absolutely right but it is displaying now as [[  .... ]] and i want [...]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is access the "result" item. Don't push it onto another array.

```
<?php

 $query =  array('$or' => array(
    array('employeeList'=>array('$exists' => false)),
    array('employeeList'=>array('$eq' => null)),
    array('employeeList'=>array('$eq' => ",")),
    array('employeeList'=>array('$eq' => ""))
));

$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$match' => $query
    ),
    array(
        '$lookup' => array(
            'from' => 'userTbl',
            'localField' => 'user_id',
            'foreignField' => 'uid',
            'as' => 'userdetails'
        )
    ),
);

$output = $this->db->broadcastTbl->aggregate($pipeline);

$result = $output["result"];
```